# Can you put a function call in an AngularJS expression?

Tags: angularjs, function, call

I am following W3School's Angular course and I am confused as to why I cannot put a function call in an Angular expression -just for fun even if may not be best practice if I find that out  later:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function add() { return 5+5 }
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app>
<p>My first expression: {{ add() }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can! But you need to declare the function in corresponding `$scope` first.

Comment: Because this function gets called on the scope which you don't have here. You need to go through some kind of "Hello world" tutorial to understand how it gets done.

Comment: not any function but those which are there in the scope/rootscope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but the function needs to be defined in the controller since that is where the `{{ }}` notation directs Angular to look.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.add = () => {
      return 5 + 5;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  {{ $ctrl.add() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Global functions are by default bound to `window` object. So, if you have the function in `window` object, you can bind it directly to the controller's `$scope` and use it in your template.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.add = $window.add;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
function add() { return 5+5 }
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ add() }}
</div>
```